# Set input[text] value according to radio button

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm trying to set the value of an input corresponding to the selected radio button, but I just can't figure out how.

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="provider" v-model="selected_provider">

<b-radio-group v-model="provider_options">
    <div class="field">

        <template v-for="provider in providers">
            <b-radio
                name="select_provider[]" id="provider_@{{ $index }}"
                model="selected_provider"
                value="provider"
                type="radio">
                @{{ provider.provider_name }}
            </b-radio>
        </template>

    </div>
</b-radio-group>
```

I've managed to get an array to display and that the input shows whatever is written in `selected_provider`, but I just don't know how to link those together.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
        data: {
            selected_provider: '',
                providers: [
                    {
                        provider_name: 'Twitch',
                        provider_url: 'https://www.twitch.tv/'
                    },
                    {
                        provider_name: 'Smashcast',
                        provider_url: 'https://www.smashcast.tv/'
                    },
                    {
                        provider_name: 'AzubuFrost',
                        provider_url: 'https://www.smashcast.tv/'
                    }
                ]
            },
        });
```

furthermore I'd like to attach the value of

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name">
```

to the end of `provider_url` in `selected_provider`

Is someone so kind to help me?

Comment: When Twitch is selected, what do you want to appear in Stream URL (and anywhere else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your for-loop to `v-for="(provider, index) in providers"`You can put a `v-on:click="setSelectedProvider(index)"` inside `<b-radio></b-radio>` and can create a method that looks like this:

```
setSelectedProvider: function(index){
    this.$set(this, 'selected_provider', index);
}
```

Whenever a radio button is clicked this will set selected_provider to the index of the clicked radio button.

As for attaching the value of your other input to the end of `provider_url`, you can create a method that does this:

```
updateProviderURL: function(event){ 
    this.$set(this.providers[this.selected_provider], 'provider_url', 
    'https://www.twitch.tv/' + event.currentTarget.value);
}
```

You can then add a listener to your input that looks like this:

```
v-on:input="updateProviderURL($event)"
```

It's good to set `selected_provider` by default to `0` inside the data part of your component so that the `updateProviderURL` function never tries to set a part of the array that doesn't exist ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've implemented what you said. For some reason `id="provider_@{{ $index }}"` does not get converted to `id="provider_0"`, `id="provider_1"` etc.

Unfortunately nothing seems to work like it should xD

Comment: Thx, that makes it easier to try some stuff myself. I'll have a look

Comment: first thing that you can try is to replace the `id="provider_@{{ $index }}"` and `for="provider_@{{ $index }}"` with `:id="'provider_' + index"` and `:for="'provider_' + index"`. That solves some errors that show up in the console. Furthermore, I'm not exactly sure how it should work, so try that and let me know ;)

Comment: Now it creates the `id="provider_0"`. https://jsfiddle.net/5w1t6xya/8/ And on jsfiddle it fills the input with the index, but not with the `provider_url`

Comment: Managed to get it to fill with the provider_url.
Had to change `v-on:click="setSelectedProvider(index)"`to `v-on:click="setSelectedProvider(provider.provider_url)"` and it seems not to work with `b-radio` but only with regular ìnput type="radio"`